# How to integrate paypal IPN dispute notifacation

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

So I recently got my IPN setup which handles my payments the way I want them to, but how do I check if a user has disputed the payment? I'm new to IPNs so do I need to integrate some sort of new code INTO the same ipn.php such as `if (preg_match('/Completed/', $payment_status)) {` should I have like `if (preg_match('/Disputed/', $payment_status)) {` or something, I how would I do this?

Comment: What does the API say to do?

Comment: The API should have a way to send alerts on disputed payments. Have you looked at that?

Comment: There is no "Disputed" payment status. [See this IPN and PDT reference for more information](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EBC0E05Z). You should be able to capture Disputes using this.

Comment: Where do I put this?? Do I just integrate like a if($txn_type) { insert query } in my ipn.php?

Comment: I just created an API in paypal, how do i integrate it?

Answer (score 0):

For disputes you will get an IPN with a txn_type of "new_case".  Within your code you can add logic to check for this and react accordingly.